# Push to multiple remote repos in, using GitExtensions

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have two remote repositories "origin" and "upstream". I would like when I click the "Push" button, my git extensions to push to both repos.

[image]

Do you know for any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The dialog in your screenshot is for configuring git remotes. You can push multiple remotes in the "Push" dialog:

[image]

Though, I can't help but wonder whether you *really need* to push to multiple remotes. In the past 10 years I had to simultaneously push to multiple remotes once or twice.
This may be a good opportunity for you to review your workflow.